# how to convert a negative numeric to postive in sql

Tags: sql, mysql, type-conversion

I want to convert -2.07 to 207 but using ABS() as shown; it returns 200 not 207.
Please help me understand what I am missing here. Thanks.

```
 declare @ReimbursementCents int,
 @journey_fare numeric(7,2)
 SET @journey_fare = -2.07

 SET @ReimbursementCents = convert(int,ABS(@journey_fare)) * 100
 if (@ReimbursementCents > 0)
 print @ReimbursementCents
```

Comment: cast(ABS(@journey_fare)*100 as UNSIGNED) or something to that effect. What's happening now is that it's converting to an integer before multiplying by 100. So -2.07 to 2.07 to 2 then *100

Comment: Maybe just `(ABS(@journey_fare) * 100) DIV 1` ?

Comment: mysql <> sql-server the published code won't syntax in mysql